# Win 8.1 laptop cant find any dnla devices in same network

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, xbox360, smart-tv

I have sony vaio svs1511 laptop upgraded to windows 8.1, xbox one, and LG SmartTV (2014 year model, with WebOS). They are all in the same 5GHz wi-fi network (I've checked that), pings from my laptop to console and TV are all ok.

But, when I try to find device in "Devices and Printers" in control panel, I cannot find neiter TV or Xbox.

I've tried various tips and tricks that are on the internet, but with no luck. Can someone suggest what to do? Maybe my laptop needs some special wi-fi driver? Or ipv6 needs to be disabled? Is there any sort of logs, where I can see why my laptop cant recognize network devices as DNLA-enabled ones?

Comment: [How to – Set up DLNA on your devices](http://tech.firstpost.com/news-analysis/how-to-set-up-dlna-on-your-devices-26991.html)